# BIOS int 0x13 modifies CS:IP?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-16, bootloader, real-mode

I'm writing an x86 bootloader which occupies two sections (1024 bytes) on disk and the first thing I want it to do is to load both sections to segment `0x60` before continuing execution

Here is the relocation part of my code:

```
_start:
  // relocate and load remaining bootloader code    
  mov $0x60, %ax
  mov %ax, %es

  mov $0x02, %ah
  mov $2, %al
  xor %bx, %bx
  mov $0, %ch
  mov $2, %cl
  xor %dh, %dh

  int $0x13

  jmp $0x60, $reloc_done

reloc_done:
  // set up segment registers
  mov $0x60, %ax
  mov %ax, %ds
  mov %ax, %es

  // set up stack
  mov $0x8000, %bx
  mov %bx, %ss
  xor %ax, %ax
  mov %ax, %sp
```

This does not seem to work however, I have tried to debug my code with gdb by creating an ELF file `boot.elf` in addition to a flat binary and executing `add-symbol-file boot.elf 0x60` followed by `break reloc_done` after attaching gdb to the qemu process running my binary. I would have expected a `continue` to then actually hit the breakpoint at `0x60:reloc_done` but this doesn't happen. What's wrong here?

When I single step through this program, it looks like the `int $0x13` actually *modifies* CS:IP to `F000:E3FE` which I do not understand at all.

EDIT: A minimal example trying to integrate some suggestions by MichaelPetch:

`boot.S:`

```
// real mode code
.code16

.global _start

jmp $0x0, $_start

_start:
  mov $0x8000, %ax
  mov %ax, %sp

  // relocate and load remaining bootloader code
  mov $0x60, %ax
  mov %ax, %es
  xor %bx, %bx

  mov $0x02, %ah
  mov $2, %al
  mov $0, %ch
  mov $1, %cl
  xor %dh, %dh

  int $0x13

  jmp $0x60, $reloc_done

reloc_done:
  nop

  // set up segment registers
  mov $0x60, %ax
  mov %ax, %ds
  mov %ax, %es

  // set up stack
  mov $0x8000, %bx
  mov %bx, %ss
  xor %ax, %ax
  mov %ax, %sp
```

`boot.ld:`

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386");

ENTRY(_start);

SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x0;
  .text : {
      *(.text);
      . = 510;
      SHORT(0xAA55);
  }

  .data : SUBALIGN(2) {
      *(.data);
      *(.rodata*);
  }

  /DISCARD/ : {
      *(.eh_frame);
      *(.comment);
  }
}
```

Compiled like this:

```
gcc -m32 -fno-PIC -g -gdwarf -Wall -Werroro -c asm/boot.S -o out/boot_S.o
ld -melf_i386 -Tout/boot.ld out/boot_S.o -o ../elf/boot.elf
objcopy -O binary ../elf/boot.elf ../img/boot.img
```

`boot.img` is then copied to the first sector of a disk image. Now the initial instruction executed is not `mov $0x60, %ax` but something else entirely.

ANOTHER EDIT: I think I got it now, I had to change the link address in my linker script as suggested by MichaelPetch but then also remove the initial `jmp $0x0, ...` from my code which didn't make sense anymore.

Comment: Every kind of function call, branch, or interrupt modifies CS:IP. It looks like your debugger stepped into the BIOS code.

Comment: @interjay: You're right, CS:IP does point into BIOS ROM after the interrupt, I didn't realize that, I thought gdb's "next" would step over interrupts.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I'm using a gdb script that handles segment:offset addressing. What I'm doing now is to first break on the `jmp 0x60:reloc_done` instruction, then reload `boot.elf` at address `0x600` (in my question I used `0x60` which is obviously wrong). When I then continue single stepping it seems to work at first but then instructions/assembly lines are skipped seemingly at random so something is still wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is that after the jmp, CS is `0x60` which is fine but IP should be decremented by `0x7C00` for CS:IP to point to where I want it to point. But I don't know how to make that happen, GAS rejects `jmp $0x60, $reloc_done - $0x7C00`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I'm not sure I understand, my linker script begins with `. = 0x7C00;  .text : { ...`, i.e. load address `0x7C00` and link address (by default I assume, because adding `AT(0)` doesn't change anything) zero.

Comment: Is the code we are looking at in your initial boot sector (sector 1) that is loaded at physical address 0x07c00? If it is shouldn't you be reading 2 sectors starting at CHS=(0,0,1) sector it to 0x0060:0x0000. As it is you are reading starting at CHS(0,0,2)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: true, that was a typo.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: But how can I change that without breaking the reloading code itself? Do I have to manually jump to 0x0:0x7C00 at the very beginning of my code?

Comment: Your reloading code (before the JMP) doesn't need to be in a specific place in memory so it will work as expected. Change your code to read 2 sectors starting from CHS=(0,0,1) and change the VMA to 0x0000 in the linker script by changing to `. = 0x0000`. You may need to get a better understanding of segment offset addressing to understand what is going on. Alternatively you can set the VMA to 0x0600 in the linker script and do `jmp $0x0000, $reloc_done` and set ES to 0x0000 instead of 0x0060

Comment: What you should do is create an [mcve] showing your bootloader, linker script and the commands you use to build everything.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: When I make the change in my linker script, IP is not at `0x7C00` when the bootloader starts executing, I will create an example.

Comment: The BIOS will start executing your code at physical address 0x07c00 . In fact you don't even know what CS was used by the BIOS to reach that. Some BIOSes will do JMP 0x07c0:0000 to reach your bootloader and others will do 0x0000:0x7c00. Whichever way it is reached the code before the JMP has to not rely on its position in memory (which your code doesn't). The only thing that needs to be right is the JMP and that will depend on the VMA (ORG) that is used. Whether you use 0x0000 as a VMA or 0x7c00 as a VMA the BIOS will start running your code at physical address 0x07c00

Comment: What I recommend you do is take your original code and do `objdump -D boot.elf` and look at what the JMP was encoded as and you may understand what is going wrong.

Comment: I would also be surprised if this worked `add-symbol-file boot.elf 0x60` . Even with your script GDB has no notion of segment:address addressing. In `add-symbol-file boot.elf 0x60` the address would have to be relative to the beginning of memory which would be 0x600 and not 0x60.

Comment: By the way something you left out of your initial question was the fact that there was code before `_start`. The edit makes it clear that wasn't the case. Remove the `jmp $0x0, $_start` as it isn't really necessary. You will be setting the CS to 0x0060 with the FAR JMP after that anyway. This is why it is always important to create an [mcve] because I had no idea there was anything before `_start`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yes, in combination with the changed link address that seems to work now. The `0x60` was another typo. Thanks a lot, I have been at this for quite a while.